# Разница между словами "незначительный" и "малозначительный"

Tags: грамотная-речь, словообразование

Зачем нужно слово "малозначительный", если уже есть "незначительный"? Чем оно отличается от него?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Области применения этих слов не совпадают. Слово "незначительный" широко применяется для количественных оценок (незначительные отклонения, ущерб и т.п. - сопоставление с мерой) и поэтому не очень подходит для рассуждений о сравнительной значимости людей (исторических фигур, персонажей). "Губернатор такой-то был очень популярен, но исторически это фигура малозначительная" (сопоставление с другими людьми эпохи; условная оценка влиятельности).

Comment: Спасибо, Александр!

Answer (score 1):

Артем, Денис прав: разница в проявлении признака.

**НЕЗНАЧИТЕЛЬНЫЙ,**

1. Небольшой по размерам, численности, величине, силе и т. п.;
2. **Не имеющий существенного значения; маловажный, малозначащий.** Н-ая фраза. Н-ая ошибка. Н-ая роль. // **Не доставляющий больших затруднений, неудобств и т. п.** Н-ая просьба. Оказать незначительную услугу. // Не имеющий большого значения, веса в обществе. Н-ая должность. Н. чин.
3. ***Ничем не замечательный, неприметный.*** Н-ая личность, фигура. Н-ое лицо. <Незначительно, наречие (1-2 зн.). Н. пострадать. Н. ошибиться. Незначительность, -и; ж. Н. потери, убытка. Н. ошибки. Н. человека, должности.

**МАЛОЗНАЧИТЕЛЬНЫЙ,**

1. ***Не имеющий большого значения, большой важности; незначительный.***
2. Не имеющий большого авторитета, не обладающий каким-л. влиянием на кого-, что-л. М. человек. М. инженер. М-ая газета.
3. ***Недостаточно большой по размерам, количеству, степени проявления и т. п.***

Обратите в словарной статье на ключевые слова, которые в своем ответе дал Денис.

Comment: Меня зовут Денис, а ник - лишь стилизация, возможно не вполне удачная))

Comment: Хорошо, буду знать. ))

Comment: Спасибо, Серж! Нужен какой-то пример, где эти слова употреблены рядом в разных значениях, чтобы в этом убедиться.

Comment: Артем,  разница не в значениях, а в степени проявления признака. Ср.: М-ая сумма. Н-ая сумма денег.

Answer (score 0):

- *Незначительный* - совсем/вовсе не играющий роли.
- *Малозначительный* - играющий небольшую роль.

То есть между этими словами есть небольшая градация степени выраженности признака.

Comment: А мне кажется, что насчёт "совсем/вовсе" вы неправы. Я понимаю *незначительный* так же, как вы определили *малозначительный*.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Тут степень варьирования признака столь мала, что может быть в ряде ситуаций несущественна вовсе: *абсолютно незначительный* - *незначительный* - *малозначительный* - *средней значимости* и т.д.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Т.е. в ситуации, когда автор употребляет оба слова рядом будет понятно отношение степени выраженности признака между ними. Если в разных контекстах - они могут считаться синонимами.